# Crop bi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a bi-dimensional array made of 0s and 1s.
I need to 'crop' the array so there are no rows / columns that only have 0s in them.

This is how I created the array.

```
var image = [];
for (y = 0; y < height; y++) 
{
    image[y] = [];
}
```

Image example of the array.
[image]

And this is what I need the array to be cropped to.
[image]

Comment: Find your first row with a 1, first column with a 1, which is your starting row, column of the crop, then search backwards for the last row with a 1, and last column with a 1, and that's your row and column of the end of the crop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should clean the rows by detecting if a an array is full of zeros.
You can use `Array.prototype.every`.
Example : 
This function return is an array is empty or not.
    function isEmpty(arr) {
        return arr.every(function(item) {
            return item===0;
        });
    }

And you can write an algorithm that detect each rows from 0 until you have a not empty line. And you make the same thing from the end of the array.

After cleaning the rows, you do the do the same thing for cols, and using the same algorithm by using a function that give you each cols as an array.

Here is a complete example that do the job :

```
var arr  = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
];


function cleanRows(arr) {
    var i=0;
    var j=arr.length-1;

    while(i<arr.length && isEmpty(arr[i])) {
        i++;
    }
    while(j>i && isEmpty(arr[j])) {
        j--;
    }
    return arr.slice(i,j+1);
}

function cleanCols(arr) {
    var i= 0, j=arr[0].length-1;

    while(i<j && isEmpty(getCol(arr,i))) {
        i++;
    }
    while(j>i && isEmpty(getCol(arr,j))) {
        j--;
    }
    j++;

    // clear each line
    return arr.map(function(row) {
        return row.slice(i,j);
    })
}

function getCol(arr,colIndex) {
    return arr.map(function(item) {
        return item[colIndex];
    });
}

function isEmpty(arr) {
    return arr.every(function(item) {
        return item===0;
    });
}

var newArr = cleanRows(arr);
newArr = cleanCols(newArr);

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: It works wonderfully, I already implemented it in a similar manner. Marked as answer!